# vb.net How do I stop DataGridView from displaying the state of a checkbox (True/False) during a mouseover event

Tags: vb.net, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I use DataGridView with a CheckBox column and when cursor hovers over a checkbox at runtime the checkboxes display what is similar to a tooltip that says either True or False depending on the state of the checkbox and I don't want that.  How do I turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `DataGridView.ShowCellToolTips` property to `false`

Take a look at the [Microsoft Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/add-tooltips-to-individual-cells-in-a-wf-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)